# NTFS partition not clearly unmounted PLEASE HELP

Tags: boot, wubi, filesystem, ntfs

When ubuntu boots, I get this error:

> The NTFS partition was not cleanly unmounted.  This probably indicates that the system was not shut down properly.  Please `run chkdsk /r` from Windows; once that is fixed you should be able to resume the installation. Press OK to reboot.

I tried that and nothing special happened (except that error again).

What should I do?

Comment: Assuming that you were booting Windows from that partition, I believe you should be getting a message asking if you want to schedule the chkdsk, and after saying yes you have to reboot Windows again and wait quite a while for it to run before bringing all of Windows up. Is that what happened?

Comment: Yes. That happened.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are doing when this happens and when you get the message? This is happening sometime during installation?

Comment: @johnsgruber I installed ubuntu using wubi a long time ago. Then it booted and I got a small window titled installation. First it told me to delete root.disk and I deleted it. Then I got "The NTFS partition was not cleanly unmounted. This probably indicates that the system was not shut down properly. Please run "chkdsk /r" from Windows; once that is fixed you should be able to resume the installation. Press OK to reboot."