# chkdsk /r problems

Tags: installation, wubi, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NTFS partition not clearly unmounted PLEASE HELP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170852/ntfs-partition-not-clearly-unmounted-please-help)

I got the below error message every time I try to boot up in Linux. I have done all the Wubi stuff properly. I ran `chkdsk /r` as the administrator in command prompt and restarted my computer. It went through an almost 3 hour process of checking the disk, then it restarted and I booted into windows like it told me too, when I restarted and booted to Ubuntu and I got the same error message. It is really frustrating because I have been trying to install Ubuntu for almost 2 days now.

Thanks guys

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have some sort of raid setup. Please provide that info.